# How do I get and process the JSON change object?

Tags: watchman

I'm using Facebook watchman on Linux under bash to track file system
changes.

I'm confused about how to get the change JSON object. All I seem to
get is a list of the changed files. I setup a watch and a trigger as
below:

```
watchman watch /Users/osx/Applications/docker/tests watchman --
trigger /Users/osx/Applications/docker/tests 'file-sync' \
             -- /Users/osx/Applications/docker/filewatcher/file-sync.sh
```

However when I query the arguments past to the file-sync.sh script it
looks like just a text field rather than a JSON object.

Do I need to do anything else to actually get the full details of all
the changes that are happening on the root?

```
watchman trigger-list shows the following results: {   "version":
"4.9.0",   "triggers": [
    {
      "command": [
        "/Users/osx/Applications/docker/filewatcher/file-sync.sh"
      ],
      "stdin": [
        "name",
        "exists",
        "new",
        "size",
        "mode"
      ],
      "append_files": true,
      "name": "file-sync",
      "empty_on_fresh_instance": true
    }   ] }
```

From what I understand this should give me a JSON object with the
name,exists,new,size and mode components.

In the system log i can see the following:

```
2019-01-15T22:28:49,191: [trigger file-sync
/Volumes/UserData/osx/Applications/docker/tests] input_json: sending
json object to stm
```

What is stm?

In the system log I can see the following:

```
2019-01-15T22:28:49,191: [trigger file-sync 
/Volumes/UserData/osx/Applications/docker/tests] input_json: sending 
`enter code here`json object to stm
```

In my bash script I use jq to dump the JSON output to stdout

```
$(echo jq '.' $1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Watchman will pass a list of file names to your trigger program in the argument vector, and the json data will be supplied to it on its *stdin stream*.

You can change your bash script to do:

```
jq '.'
```

and it should show you the data of interest.

#### Consider using watchman-make rather than triggers

I'd like to note that triggers are a bit hard to use and debug because they log to the watchman server log and are hard to see into.  For that reason I tend to push folks towards using [watchman-make](https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/watchman-make.html), which runs in the foreground and has clear messaging about what is happening.  For example, assuming that you are going to trigger an `rsync`, you can probably get away with doing something like:

```
cd /Users/osx/Applications/docker/tests && \
   watchman-make -p '**/*' \
      --run /Users/osx/Applications/docker/filewatcher/file-sync.sh
```

and then `file-sync.sh` can be something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
rsync /Users/osx/Applications/docker/tests somewhere:else
```

Note that this pattern "loses" the list of changed files, but rsync is going to compare the directory structures anyway, and most directory trees tend to be small
enough that you won't mind.

If you want or need to make it incremental you can have your script call back into watchman; something like this will list the files changed since the last time it was run:

```
watchman since /Users/osx/Applications/docker/tests n:file-sync
```

The `n:file-sync` is a named cursor; the server will keep track of the internal clock data on your behalf each time you query using it in a since query.   You can find more information about this here: https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/clockspec.html

Comment: Thank you Wez so much for your quick response.

Comment: Just adding the jq '.' to my script gave me access to the JSON object. I need to be able to capture all changes (new,updated and deleted) and also want a robust solution that is responsive and able to handle potentially large roots and act on the changes as fast as possible. I like that the trigger gives me immediate notification that i can act upon.

Comment: You mentioned that  watchman-make would lose the list of changes. It looks like rsync would again do some form of change tracking. So would there not be duplicate work happening and would i not loose some of the tracking ability of watchman?

Comment: Are there any guidelines on possible approaches or use cases and when to use each approach?

Comment: Can you also explain the JSON that you get when a file is updated: [
  {
    "mode": 0,
    "new": true,
    "size": 0,
    "exists": false,
    "name": "file.log.sb-f5914475-w3lcsW"
  },
  {
    "mode": 33188,
    "new": false,
    "size": 71,
    "exists": true,
    "name": "file.log"
  },
  {
    "mode": 0,
    "new": true,
    "size": 0,
    "exists": false,
    "name": "file.log.sb-f5914475-JN2nat"
  }
]

Comment: It looks like for each file change you get the changed file plus i guess before and after information? How would i interpret the .sb-....... JSON information?

Comment: The ` { "mode": 0, "new": true, "size": 0, "exists": false, "name": "file.log.sb-f5914475-w3lcsW" },` entry is watchman telling you about a temporary file that was created and removed; its `exists` value is false so it no longer exists.  It is a common pattern to write to a temporary file and then atomically rename it to the desired filename, which appears to be `file.log` in this case.  I'd recommend not putting log files for your sync/watch stuff in the directory you are watching, to avoid a loop and loading the system.

Comment: Regarding triggers giving you immediate feedback: often in a file sync scenario you'll want to wait until writes have settled down before you trigger a sync, otherwise you risk kicking off your sync several times while the file is being written to the watched directory.   `watchman-make` has a convenient `--settle` flag for this purpose, whereas triggers have a coarser grained settle configuration for the entire server that is configurable via `.watchmanconfig`: https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/config.html#settle

Comment: Regarding guidelines: if the directory you are watching holds fewer than 100,000 files/directories, the dumb sounding `watchman-make` + `rsync` approach I mentioned will likely be fine and will be the easiest thing to manage, understand and maintain.

If your system is continually doing a lot of IO and you have a lot of files then you might legitimately need to go more complex.  I would suggest the variation of `watchman-make` + named cursor in that situation as an easy solution to make finely grained and incremental.

Comment: If you really need realtime response to changes and precise programmatic control I would suggest to ignore all of this and use either `pywatchman` or the `fb-watchman` nodejs client and use `subscriptions` instead.

`watchman-make` uses pywatchman in that way; here's its code: https://github.com/facebook/watchman/blob/master/python/bin/watchman-make

You can find examples of using the nodejs client in the docs here: https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/nodejs.html

Comment: Thanks again Wez. Initially i was thinking of using bash scripts. Practically I am wondering what options i have if I wanted to use watchman-make and pywatchman as you suggest. Does this mean i am forced to use either nodejs or python?

Comment: I am interested in catching new, changed, renamed and deleted files/directories. How would i catch a file or directory name change?

Comment: I am interested in getting all the fields returned as in stdin in triggers. Looking at the python watchman-make was very useful except that it only passes back the name field in the query. Can this be extended or would I have to basically clone watchman-make and add the other fields i am interested in?